# Function for confidence intervals error code {

Tags: r, brackets

together with you, I have recently made the following function (the content is not important right now). It seems to be correct but when I try to process it, the following error turns up: **Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"**. Do you know what I´ve made wrong?

Here´s the function, thank you in advance (btw I have checked every bracket):

**Edit: Now it works:**

```
CI <- function(x, s, z, Fall) {

if (Fall == "Fall1") {
result <- mean(x) + c(-1,1)* qnorm(1-z/2)*(s/sqrt(length(x)))


} else if (Fall == "Fall2") {
result <- mean(x) + c(-1,1)* qt(p=1-a/2, df=length(x)-     1)*(sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)))
```

} else if (Fall == "Fall3") {
result <-mean(x)+c(-1,1)*qnorm(1-z/2*(s/sqrt(length(x))))

} else if (Fall == "Fall4"){
result <- mean(x)+c(-1,1)*qt(p=1-a/2, df=length(x)-1)*(sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)))

} else {result<-NA}

return(result)
}

CI(x=x, s=15, z=0.05, Fall="Fall1")

Comment: In your last `else`, it shouldn't have a condition i.e. `else  {result <-..` or you have to use `else if` and the the last as `else {result <- NA}` ...

Comment: Sorry, i mistook the input sd for s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of errors - 1) `else` would not have a condition check, instead use `else if`, 2), the values to compare should be quoted `"Fall1"`

```
CI <- function(x, mean, sd, z, Fall)
  {
  if (Fall == "Fall1") {
    result <- mean(x) + c(-1, 1) * qnorm(1 - z / 2) * (sd / sqrt(length(x)))
    
    
  } else if (Fall == "Fall2") {
    result <-
      mean(x) + c(-1, 1) * qt(p = 1 - a / 2, df = length(x) - 1) * (sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)))
    
    
  } else if (Fall == "Fall3") {
    result <- mean(x) + c(-1, 1) * qnorm(1 - z / 2 * 
  (sd / sqrt(length(x))))
    
    
  } else if (Fall == "Fall4") {
    result <-
      mean(x) + c(-1, 1) * qt(p = 1 - a / 2, df = length(x) - 1) * (sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)))
  }
  else {
    result <- NA_real_
  }
  
  
  return(result)
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, my function works. Have a nice day!

Comment: @seboe i made the changes